# ASP.NET After Log In, every other connection is logged in

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web, logout

I am making a project for school. I have a website coded in ASP.Net and I just made a simple log in system. When the user enters the email and password, I query the database and make sure they are valid.

At this point I want to know who logged in so I have a class called User.cs to keep track of the logged in person.

```
public class User
{
    static public bool loggedIn = false;
    static public int userType = -1;//1 = Agent, 2 = Buyer/Renter
    static public int id = -1;//the id of the user
}
```

For example inside `User.cs`, there is a variable called `bool loggedIn` . After log in button click, i set it to `true` so that during `Page_Load()` i can make log in/sign up button invisible if I need to. I deployed the website with IIS and tested it by logging in from a computer, worked great. And then I logged in from another computer and I was still logged in as the last user from the first log in. I logged out and I was logged out from all other computers which I opened the website from as well.

So in the end, I am not sure how to make a proper log in system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the first problem that you have is the logged in user information is `static`. It's available to ***all instances*** of the application because of that. So, when you login, that's the user that's logged in ***everywhere,*** and when you log out, you're logged out ***everywhere.***

So, let's fix up the `User` class shall we:

```
public class User
{
    public bool loggedIn = false;
    public int userType = -1;//1 = Agent, 2 = Buyer/Renter
    public int id = -1;//the id of the user
}
```

there we go, that will fix the span of the logged in user to their instance. But we're not done just yet, we need to store that information somewhere so you can recover it on post backs and such. Let's use `Session` for that, it makes sense because they are logged in for a **session** right? So on `Page_Load`, when you verify the user, do this also:

```
var usr = new User
{
    loggedIn = true,
    userType = ?,    // pull this value from the database
    id = ?           // pull this value from the database
};
Session["User"] = usr;
```

and now when you want to get at that user you can pull it out of `Session`:

```
var usr = Session["User"] as User;
// if usr is null then there is no logged in user
// otherwise, if it's NOT null there is a logged in user for this session
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. So when logIntButton_Click happens inside logInPage.Master.cs, I create a User object with non-static variables and then put this new User object instance in Session. After this loginButton_Click I redirect the user to the HomePage.aspx. The Page_Load() function of HomePage.Master.cs I need to access Session and see if there is a logged in user so that I can decide to reveal "Create a Listing" button. But now session has to be a global variable? Wouldn't this create the same problem ?

Comment: @Yunus, Session is by definition not a global variable, it's a special dictionary available in fact to the session that's created on IIS when a user accesses your site from a browser. That session is managed and loaded based off of cookies, IP addresses, and other mechanisms.

Comment: That is very interesting, I did not know that. I thought session was another class I had to write. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First Method: When user clicked on logout then loggedIn variable in User class changed to false again.

But The right ways is that in backend database you have to add a new column in user table that "IsLoggedIn". its default value is 0 as false and when user logged in then make its true. So for this you can easily track that who is online or not.